# attach onclick change image to varing img amount with no id tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I would know how to do this with no problem if the images had id tags but im lost on how to do this without them.

http://jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/

I want to click a thumbnail and have the large picture change.

Problems:

1. the amount of images varies so Im hoping for a way of attaching the click event to all the elements.
2. the images don't have an id tag
3. I cant edit the html directly only through javascript and jquery.

main pic:

```
  <div id="IDX-primaryPhoto" class="IDX-detailsPhotoWrap">
  <a href="">
  <img src="CAT9536786.jpg" id="IDX-detailsPhoto">
 </a>
 </div>
```

thumbnails:

```
 <div id="IDX-detailsShowcase">

    <div class="IDX-showcaseSlide" id="IDX-detailsImage1">
        <div class="IDX-showcaseContent">
        <img alt="Property Photo" src="CAT9536786.jpg" class="IDX-detailsShowcaseImage">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="IDX-showcaseSlide" id="IDX-detailsImage2">
        <div class="IDX-showcaseContent">
        <img alt="Property Photo" src="CAT9536786A.jpg" class="IDX-detailsShowcaseImage">
        </div> 
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Your thumbnails have a class. You can use that as your jquery selector. `$('.IDX-detailsShowcaseImage')` http://jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/2/

Comment: @PedroEstrada write that as an answer +1 for the working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my answer as requested by OP.

Your thumbnails have a class. You can use that as your jquery selector.

`$('.IDX-detailsShowcaseImage')`

Therefore:

```
$('.IDX-detailsShowcaseImage').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).prop('src'); //grab the src of the thumbnail
    $('#IDX-detailsPhoto').prop('src', href); //set it as the big image
});
```

[jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/2](http://jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/2)

Comment: make that jsfiddle a link

Comment: lol .... Hey @PedroEstrada any idea whats wrong here http://jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/5/

Comment: @tman seems like `.prop()` isn't a method in your jquery library... try using `attr()` http://jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/6/

Comment: @tman also, don't use `<script>` `<html>` etc. tags in jsfidlle. For scripts use the resources option. I deleted those and is working... again. Both jQuery declared could be the culprit.

Comment: @Braiam I tried it out on my page prior to just dumping it in the jsfiddle and it didn't work no worries though i got it going now!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an id to attach event handlers or to use any of the jQuery functions for that matter, jQuery provides a [large number of selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that you can use and combine to get the elements that you need. In your case, your images already have a class so use the class selector:

```
$('.IDX-detailsShowcaseImage').click(your_function);
```

Comment: so i could then pass the source to the main image ...? $(this).src

Comment: that's right, inside your handler function `$(this)` will refer to the jQuery object of the image that was clicked

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery attach on click to all images like so:

```
$(document).on("click", ".IDX-detailsShowcaseImage img", function(){
     var img_src = $(this).attr('src')
     //your code here
});
```

So you can dynamically create your `<img>` elements and still respond to all click events and access the element that triggered the event with `$(this)`.

Comment: I have other images on the page aswell sry I forgot to mention

Comment: @tman no worries modified the answer to include the class selector.

Comment: @tman saw you asked about accessing the `src` attribute, added that to the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery selectors to select all child elements of certain class/id

```
$(".IDX-showcaseSlide img").click(function);
```

Answer (score 0):

This uses no id's and works for all of the details images:

```
$(".IDX-detailsShowcaseImage").click(function(arg) {
    $(".IDX-detailsPhotoWrap img").attr('src', $(arg.target).attr('src'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2GwEm/9/